# React-Native Keystore file not set for signing config release

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a release .apk file in React Native without success.
I followed all the instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html), but i always get the same result after running `gradlew assembleRelease` in /my-project/android path:

```
:app:validateSigningRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

I'm using Windows 10 and i suspect it's something with the edit of file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

From my understanding ~ is c:\Users\User
I even got a c:\Users\User.gradle folder built-in.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error message, but I just fixed it.

As mention in RN documentation [**Facebook Doc**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#setting-up-gradle-variables)

> Edit the file **~/.gradle/gradle.properties** or **android/gradle.properties**

I edited another file located here

> ~/MYAPP/android/gradle.properties

Then did clean and build again.
I hope this will help.

Comment: I'm a App-Developer with different Customers and wan't to have the Project-Settings for the app inside the project-path. So I'm glad to see your comment here, because now i only put the "MYAPP_RELEASE_..." Variables into android/app/gradle.properties.
This way I don't need to adjust my global gradle-file for each customer-project sign key.
But watch out not to push this file to your GIT-Repo (add it to .gitignore)  ;)

Comment: For me editing `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I see that this thread has been inactive for almost two months, but I figured I could write down what caused this problem for me, maybe it helps someone else in the future.

It was in fact pretty simple: when I copied the configuration from the documentation the formatting was not kept, it either pasted everything on one line, or on multiple ones, but breaking the lines also in places where it shouldn't. So you just need to make sure the lines in the *build.gradle* file look like:

```
keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
```

and not

```
keyPassword 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
```

And that is it.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. I had a space after     MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore  . I remove the space and it worked.

Comment: Mine: The line storeFile file('C:\\etc was long so I had split it into two lines ::(

Answer (score 4):

You can try setting your gradle.properties variables as environment variables and change your signinConfig release in android/app/build.gradle to something like:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(String.valueOf(System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE")))
        storePassword System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
        keyAlias System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
        keyPassword System.getenv("GRADLE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD")
    }
}
```

I'm on Mac but I'm guessing environment variables should work better on Windows than the global .gradle/gradle.properties file

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Just a note for anyone else that comes across this looking for help. If you have uploaded the keystore and the password and alias to the appcenter then you do not need to have any settings in the android/gradle.properties or android/app/build.gradle the keystore file and env variables uploaded will be used to sign the apk after it has been build

Comment: Perfect, this worked, this is exactly where I was stuck. Basically, when building for AppCenter, you need to ignore the changes listed for `app/build.gradle` and `gradle.properties` in the RN documentation.

Answer (score 1):

## never forget `.keystore` extension name!

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=android-app-demo-release-key.keystore
```

Comment: react native Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Run this in your terminal and enter all essentials.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Step 2: Put my-upload-key.keystore inside ../android/app

Step 3: In android/gradle.properties (Enter your password generated from Step 1):

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=****
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=****
```

Step 4: In android/app/build.gradle file, add the following (you can also change version name of your app fro this file):

```
splits {
    .......
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        // comment the line below in production
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard- rules.pro"
    }
}
......
......
```

Step 5: After all this, you can continue with either

```
gradlew assembleRelease (for .apk file)
```

or

```
gradlew bundleRelease (for .aab file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows 10 too. You must install Git Bash command line for Windows to do this. After you install Git Bash, navigate into yourproject/android/app and execute `vim ~/.gradle/gradle.properties` this works for me.

Comment: I did that and it opened the file i already created in c:\Users\User\.gradle\gradle.properties as expected.

Comment: You navigate into yourproject/android/app and execute vim ~/.gradle/gradle.properties using Git Bash?

Answer (score 0):

I am also on Windows 10 and developing in RN v0.54.4. I got this error in this version but not for my older applications. For me, I just needed to remove the if statement that is in the React-Native docs. They tell you to do

```
release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
```

but I changed it to

```
release {
        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
```

which is the code that the docs had in an earlier version of RN.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to change generic `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` but it has `MY_APP...` vars defined on it.

For some reason I don't know my `android/app/build.gradle` `MY_APP_...` variables were resolving with the values of the generic file instead the local one. I just renamed `MY_APP...` vars to `PROJECTNAME...` in `android/app/build.gradle` and `android/gradle.properties` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after I tried many things:

- to put the password and key as strings
- comment `signingConfig signingConfigs.release`; which worked but created unsigned apk
- recreated the `*.keystore` over and over.

Eventually what I missed, was that I had to put

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

**Inside `MYAPP/android/.gradle/4.10.1/gc.properties`.
Now I know in the docs they said either in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` or `android/gradle.properties`**

But the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` didn't exist. and to put them in `android/gradle.properties` only didn't work either.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have to place in build.gradle below code .

```
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
```

You can test it by setting values directly.

```
                storeFile file('my-release-key.keystore')
                storePassword "123456"
                keyAlias "my-key-alias"
                keyPassword "123456"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `signingConfigs` in `app/build.gradle` must match with config in `gradle.properties`:

In my `gradle.properties`

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=./src/key_store/test.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=key0
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=123456
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=123456
```

In my `app/build.gradle`

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```